# Javascript - Selecting an element in a list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How do I select an element from a list using Javascript. Here is some of my code:

```
    var score = 0;
    var bin = 0;
    var question = -1;
    var answers = ['higher', 'lower', 'higher', 'lower', 'higher'];

    function answer_question(response) {
        if (response == 1) {
            if (answer[question] == "higher"){
                score ++;
                console.log(score);
            } else {
                bin ++;
                console.log("Bin: ");
                console.log(bin);
            }
        }
        else if (response == 0) {
            if (answer[question] == "lower") {
                score ++;
                console.log(score);
            } else {
                bin ++;
                console.log("Bin: ");
                console.log(bin);
            }
        }
    }
```

However it doesn't work, I think this is due to the

```
answer[question] == "higher"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `question = -1`? arrays start with `0`.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "select an element in a list"?

Comment: Your code is very confusing, can you give an example as to what these parameters do and when and how you call the functions?

Comment: how you are getting the value for `question`? is it fixed thought the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of three things:

- `answer` is not defined. I suspect you meant `answers`. This could be just a typo.
- Even if you did `answers[question]`, well, `question = -1`, and `answers[-1]` returns `undefined` in Javascript. JS does not have the concept of negative indexing, so you can't use negative numbers as index subscripts. Use any number between `0` and `answers.length - 1` instead, like so:

  ```
  answers[0] // returns 0th (first) element of answers array
  ```
- You never increment or change `question`. Every time you run this code, `answers[question]` always returns the same thing. In that case, why do you even have that line?

---

To answer your question as stated, however, array elements can be accessed by index like so: `array[index]`. `index` can be any integer between `0` and one less than the length of the array.

Comment: 1st point is probably the problem, the two others are probably because it's "some of the code" and not all the code.